# Where sitecore event handlers are located

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Where can I see the source code of sitecore predefined event handlers(e.g. item deleted event handler, OnPublishEnd and other). I want to change them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For exemple when you delete an item from Sitecore interface you have next event:

```xml
 <event name="item:deleted">
    <handler type="Sitecore.Links.ItemEventHandler, Sitecore.Kernel" method="OnItemDeleted" />
    <handler type="Sitecore.Tasks.ItemEventHandler, Sitecore.Kernel" method="OnItemDeleted" />
    <handler type="Sitecore.Globalization.ItemEventHandler, Sitecore.Kernel" method="OnItemDeleted" />
    <handler type="Sitecore.Data.Fields.ItemEventHandler, Sitecore.Kernel" method="OnItemDeleted" />
    <handler type="Sitecore.Rules.ItemEventHandler, Sitecore.Kernel" method="OnItemDeleted" />
  </event>
```

You can decompile Sitecore.Kernel.dll with Reflector or Dot Peek and to see in deep the code.

For "publish:end" you have next code

```xml
 <event name="publish:end">
    <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache>
      <sites hint="list">
        <site>website</site>
      </sites>
    </handler>
  </event>
```

This lines appear on web.config file. I suggest you to use patching, to create new config files for custom events. A good start how to use config files is [this article](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/05/All-About-Web-config-Include-Files-with-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx).

If you created a class and method for item deleted for exemple on config files under event "item:deleted" you will have :

```xml
<handler type="YourNamespace.YourClassName, YourAssembly" method="YourMethodName" />
```

Information about using events and how to do you find [here](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/API/Using%20Events.aspx).

Comment: By the way, you cannot decompile Sitcore.Kernel.dll.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to decompile Sitecore.Kernel.dll ?